# VS2005 + Crystal Report error 'The Report Application Server failed'

Tags: t-sql, visual-studio-2005, crystal-reports, xsd

I use VS2005, Crystal Report for VS2005 and Microsoft SQL Server 2005. I got a report, crystal report linked to a XSD, that displays perfectly when I call it from my application.

I added an 'image' field in my source table to add a an image to the table record (image in jpeg format). I store my image in the databse using VB.Net, the image is converted to an array of bytes. I added the field to my XSD file also, type : System.Byte().

Then I added the field to my report, now I get the message 'The Report Server failed'. I get this message on opening the report, the pop-up is displayed but never the report.

I read that when using Crystal Report & Stored Procs, it's best not to use BMP files, I tried JPG and PNG, didn't work either.

Any help? Please.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I right-click 'Insert Column' in my XSD it doesn't work, if I drag and drop the stored proc from Visual Studio's "Server Explorer" it works, go figure it out, but it works.

Comment: Adding the field from the DB directly will work because the client is handling the data.  I believe the problem is in the XML file:

System.Byte() (type="xs:base64Binary").

CR for VS 2005 does not support 64 bit XML.